# String.IsNullOrEmpty check with Data Table cell

Tags: c#, null, isnullorempty

If I have a Data Table and I want to see if the value contained within a specific cell is empty I would use this.

```
foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{
    bool isEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["MyColumn"].ToString());
}
```

but what happens if the value in `row["MyColumn"]` is `null`. Wouldn't the `.ToString()` throw an exception? Yet when I try the following ..

```
bool isEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["MyColumn"]);
```

I get an invalid argument exception because the `IsNullOrEmpty()` method is looking for a string object.

So what is the proper way to check if a specific cell in a Data Table is empty or null?

Comment: What version of C# are you using?  If it is C# 6 or above you have access to the null conditional (`?.`) operator

Comment: This is the compiler version I am running. '4.0.30319.42000'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your statement to this,

```
bool isEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["MyColumn"]?.ToString());
```

?. means run the process .ToString() only if row["MyColumn"] is not null.

Comment: Is the data type of the Data Table cell already a `nullable type`? If I were using an older version of the compiler (where `nullable types` are not supported) how would I accomplish the same thing? My compiuler version is 4.0.30319.42000. Edit: Looks like @Broots answered my question.

Comment: it doesnt have to be nullable for you to use `?.`. If the resulting data is null, `?.` means dont process any more methods on the result since it will end up with "object reference not set to instance of a method".

Comment: I see. So it is not really dependent on `nullable type` support?

Comment: Its only checking to see if value == null. Instead of writing, `value == null ? null : somethingelse`, you can use coalesced statement: `value?.somethingelse`

Answer (score 1):

Basically just adding this for the sake of completeness... but if for some reason you aren't using C# 6 or above, you can always do it the "old fashioned way":

```
bool isEmpty = row["MyColumn"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["MyColumn"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this in case `nullable types` are not available in my compiler version

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use the [`Field<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.8) method of the `DataRow`:

```
bool isEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("MyColumn"));
```

This provides strongly typed access to the row values.

You can use it with other types too, so no need to parse `int` or `DataTime`, for example.

```
var myDate = row.Field<DateTime>("MyDate");   // DateTime
var myInt = row.Field<int>("MyInt");          // int
```

It also works with `nullable` types:

```
var myDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("MyDate");  // DateTime? (Nullable)
if (myDate.HasValue) 
{
    ...
}
```